# How to fix Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I am using HTML with angular JS, and back end is java with apache2 server

```
Error: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

It is only for my javascript, the CSS and images are loading fine.

My admin enables in apache2 CORS also

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

I found many answers in stackoverflow and other site it doest show me the error what I have.

Now doubt whether this is problem of UI side or server side?

Here is my calling UI for fancybox

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe"
                       href="https://url">Registration
                    </a>
```

here is my detailed error :

```
Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://url" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Error (native)
    at new <anonymous> (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:14:11064)
    at e (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:10282)
    at Object.f [as instantiate] (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:10374)
    at https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:31165
    at link (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:10:1467)
    at fa (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:28039)
    at v (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:22123)
    at h (https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:17944)
    at https://url/ui/app.full.min.js:6:17440 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: Do you have anything wrapped in an iframe?

Comment: yes it was a fancy box. but it works fine before

Comment: Can you post some code please of where the error is occuring?

Comment: I added the error what i got @sebenalern

Answer (score 0):

sorry, It was my big mistake (actually small)

```
$window.parent.postMessage(details, window.parent.location.origin);
```

The window.parent.location.origin creates the Problem . I cannot figure out because my test and UI test in same server so it works fine before. the prod was different server , so it cause this issue.

Comment: Thank you @sebenalern for the help :)

Comment: @vimalprakash how to use this in angular js, what input is 'details'